# Choropleth maps (plotly) with detailed borders

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to plot a world map, where the colors correspond to a specific variable. However, it does not show small states like "Andorra" or "Liechtenstein", even though they are in the data frame (see `df$COUNTRY`). I think the problem is, that the borders are not drawn with much detail. Hence one can not see the small states. Is there a way draw the borders with more detail like with the packs, `maps`, and `mapdata` (e.g `wolrd_detailed <- map_data ("worldHires")`? Or any other way to make the small states visible? Here is the example from the plotly website. It does not show small states:

```
library(plotly)   
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv")
fig <- plot_ly(df, type='choropleth', locations=df$CODE, z=df$GDP..BILLIONS., text=df$COUNTRY, colorscale="Blues")
fig
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: No sadly not. I uses the packages `maps` and `mapdata`, since I could not figure it out.